# Dividing two large longs while retaining precision and accuracy

Tags: java, floating-point, long-integer, precision, division

I have two large `long` values, e.g. `long a = 106951484895` and `long b = 47666297253`. I want to divide one by the other, while still retaining precision and accuracy. `a / b` gives just `2`, which is neither precise nor accurate. `(double)a / b` returns `2.243754834308401` which is precise, but I don't know whether it is accurate. Is it accurate, or is there a better way?

Comment: Does BigDecimal ring a bell?

Comment: @Hannes Yes, but I didn't know if it was more accurate.

Comment: At least it avoids the common problems with IEEE 754 rounding error.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha gives the exact result as 2.243754834308400900535121747859167616725725368773485418854923...](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=106951484895+%2F+47666297253) Your figure is accurate to all of the displayed digits. Do you need more precision?

Comment: Hah.. Even `BigDecimal` couldn't give an exact representable value for that division. Lol :) How did you come up with those values?

Comment: @Hannes When dividing by 47666297253, there is no fundamental reason why base 10 should be better than base 2, and actually quite few why  base 2 would be better. So for this operation, BigDecimal does not avoid any fundamental problems, it just has more precision than `double`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman That is plenty accurate :)

Comment: @RohitJain I'm trying to measure exactly how much faster an operation is than another operation. Eventually I'll have it run them both `100000000000L` or more times.

Comment: @RohitJain, What do you mean by `BigDecimal` couldn't give an exact representable value for that division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [check the calculation in Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=106951484895+%2F+47666297253), you'll see that the exact result is
**2.2437548343084009**00535121747859167616725725368773485418854923... Your figure of
**2.243754834308401** is dead on. Unless you need more precision, the calculation with `double`s will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

In Java there is a `BigInteger` class, for when you need unlimited precision using whole numbers. For decimal numbers, use `BigDecimal`

Wolfram Alpha will give you `2.243754834308400900535121747859167616725725368773485418854923...`, and our figure is `2.243754834308401`, which is same as

```
bigDecimal1.divide(bigDecimal2, MathContext.DECIMAL64)
```

If you will go for

```
bigDecimal1.divide(bigDecimal2, new MathContext(1000, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)))
```

You will get

```
2.24375483430840090053512174785916761672572536877348541885492361677904883097801043287594504
1050407263946829396490609763285697017511527160785819555506643456210143732768535294645618694
7909645722613183738163350810420038396599808994188248448801742297144651257940243013656347535
1346061895880989881427322957327423437070470786123178209350642720039431463073874604572487035
0881416301899886949878414127297558394219666911873273296141755170873372894249298571586701215
5058865276866526572281643300564007415077913939597358974242706109866167162174559269200972437
4468185209762552814414640557312348785977139301334520631262090283427956618755742143233766150
5750523038219597199472866720344664485953248792408356275728443143815091921547456137582778817
3173376404446432448382818379181981559569409501831858179303080342832602945081961262782040747
0742627855109348071601512026092932232568603874560325500767085983329631127368742840999544420
8119473080650114494849915293461361824567061678496514955637978679644265088391509259402889160
```

For more accuracy you can keep increasing the precision given in the `MathContext` constructor.

This `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN` aka *Banker's rounding* is analogous to the rounding policy used for float and double arithmetic in Java.